# Does とみに here mean intensely?

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence, dictionary

> サトルは正義感がとみに強い男ではあるが、それをいいことに利用しようとすりよる輩も存在していた。

The 広辞苑 dictionary lists とみに to have the meaning of しきりに :

> しきりに。「老眼が―進んだ」「国運―衰える」

which on of its meanings is "intensely".so, does とみに here means intensely ?

Answer (score 1):

First note that [しきりに](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E9%A0%BB%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB/#je-30830) means *very often*, *many times in a short time*.

I think your interpret the writer's intention correctly. That is, it means *intensely* or more simply *particularly, notably*.

That said, it seems a wrong use of とみに.

I checked several dictionaries and all of them say とみに means 急に、にわかに = *suddenly* ([精選版日本国語大辞典](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A0%93-584822), [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A0%93%E3%81%AB_%28%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%29/#jn-160218), I checked 明鏡 and 学研現代国語辞典 as well.)

As mentioned [here](https://salon.mainichi-kotoba.jp/archives/3008#%E9%A0%93%E3%81%AB), for example, using とみに as *particularly* is a common misuse. (This means you'd never get to the true meaning by dictionary though some dictionaries may mention very common misuses.)

> 「最近とみに暑くなってきた」ならともかく「今年はとみに暑かった」は誤用といえる。「特に」の意味と間違って使っていると思われるケースが近ごろとみに目につく

---

I checked 広辞苑 and as you say, it lists しきりに as the second item. It's just a mystery to me. Both examples you wrote should be understood as 急に.

Comment: 広辞苑 lists しきりに to mean ②ひどく。むやみに。「父母の―恋し雉の声」(芭蕉)。「―気にする」 so maybe from that ?

Comment: @goldenlight Possibly. But giving a meaning based on 芭蕉 seems odd to me and しきりに気にする sounds definitely *very often* to me (and it also looks fair to understand 芭蕉's poem as *often*). I wonder why 広辞苑 gives such a subtly odd meaning. I'd say on this matter 広辞苑 has just an idiosyncratic idea.